# Javascript code isn't working. Does anyone know why?

Tags: javascript, html

As the title says the following code isn't wokring and I don't know why.

Html:

```
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input type="textbox" class="probe"></input>
    <button class="probar">h</button>
    </form>
  <p id="pu">h<p>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
//Global variables
  var poste = "";
  var wSearch= "";


 $("probar").on("click",function(){
//Doing a JSON request to wikipedia api
$.getJSON("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=jsonfm&search=America&namespace=0&limit=10&redirects=resolve&format=json&callback=?", function(data) {
//Triying to get the data returned. It doesn't works.   
  console.log(data); 
});   
  });

});
```

So it's supposed function is that when you click the "probar" button it asks for a JSON from the Wikipedia API  and it puts it into the console. That's all. And it isn't working.

Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="txtQuery" type="text" />
    <button id="btnRequest">Request</button>

    <pre id="txtResponse"><pre>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#btnRequest").click(function(){
                //Doing a JSON request to wikipedia api
                $.getJSON("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=jsonfm&search="+ $("#txtQuery").val() + "&namespace=0&limit=10&redirects=resolve&format=json&callback=?", function(data) {
                    $("#txtResponse").html(JSON.stringify(data,null,4));
                });   
            });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, it works! Don't know why, but it does, thanks.

Comment: please don't down vote answer.. tell me directly if there is any problem in answer.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't done anything to associate the JavaScript with the HTML. You need a `<script>` element for that:

```
<script src="foo.js"></script>
```

Once you do that you'll see a reference error in the Console of your browser's developer tools because `$` is not defined. You need another script element to load the jQuery library you are depending on.

Then you need to learn about [selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/).

`probar` is a type selector and will match `<probar>` elements, which are not allowed in HTML.

A class selector begins with a `.`

Comment: Thanks, but im working wiht code pen io, you don't have to do those things.
But, I missed the class selector, thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html/>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title
 <script src="javascript_file.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form>
 <input type="textbox" class="probe"></input>
 <button class="probar">h</button>
 </form>
 <p id="pu">h<p>
 </body>
 </html>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//Global variables
var poste = "";
var wSearch= "";


$(".probar").on("click",function(){ // add dot begining class selector
//Doing a JSON request to wikipedia api
$.getJSON("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?  action=opensearch&format=jsonfm&search=America&namespace=0&limit=10&redirects=resolve&format=json&callback=?", function(data) {
//Triying to get the data returned. It doesn't works.   
 console.log(data); 
 });   
 });

 });
```

Comment: input type textbox?

Comment: for select? not necessary